# Groovy modify map in list

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to modify each map in a list in my build. First stage validates the config and I want to generate the image name for each dockerfile and attach it to the map. This value is used in a later stage. Issue is the value `.image_name` is `null` still in later stages.

```
call(build = [:]) {
    def docker_files = build.docker_files

    stage("Validate") {
       steps {
        script {
           docker_files.each {
               // do validation stuff
               it.image_name = build_util.get_image_name(it)
           }
        }
      }
    }

   stage("Build") {
       steps {
        script {
           docker_files.each {
              println "${it.image_name}" // would print 'null'
              build_util.build(it)
           }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The App Jenkinsfile looks like so

```
App([
   docker_files: [
     [file: "Dockerfile", name: "blah"],
     [file: "nginx/Dockerfile", name: "nginx"]
   ]
])
```

Edit: I have since attempted the following as well to no avail

```
docker_files.eachWithIndex { it, idx ->
    it.image_name = build_util.get_image_name(it)
    docker_files[idx] = it
}
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with scoping however I have modified other values that were defined immediately inside `call`. Those modifications carried to later stages so I'm not sure why I am seeing this issue here.

Comment: Maybe build_util.get_image_name(it) returns null...

Comment: Given how the function is written that would not be possible. It returns a string concat w/ no branching.